# Eclipse ADT - Build error

Tags: android, eclipse, build, adt

I was cleaning my code using project's context menu in Eclipse, now it can't buidld.
I'm getting following error:

> Errors occurred during the build. Errors running builder 'Android Pre
>   Compiler' on project 'MyAPP'. Path must include project and
>   resource name: /MyAPP

Additionally, Eclipse can't see android.R. Before cleaning code everything was working good, now I can't undo it.

Comment: Did try to restart the eclipse adt?

Comment: Delete the project and import it again?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you resolve this?